# How do I join values from multiple rows into one textbox (or one string)

Tags: ms-access

My problem is rather simple, I'm new to MS Access. I want to put data from multiple rows into one textbox/label and also add some strings to it. I just can't get it to work.

I have a [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiLkj.jpg) with some laptops and their parameters like CPU, CPU manufacturer, number of cores etc. and tables for all used CPUs, all manufacturers, etc.

Then I have a report with all the laptops and their specs (looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1omQ.jpg)). Currently, each column has its own textbox, and each custom string is in its own label as I haven't figured out a better solution.

The problem is, that approach looks just bad. I'd like to have each "component" on a single line, in one textbox/label, so it's all nicely aligned.

I've tried using queries, but they either showed an #error, syntax error or displayed some nonsense like AMD Core i7. I've been putting them into the "Control source":

```
[0_PRODUKTY]![Počet jader CPU]+"core processor "+[0_PRODUKTY]![Značka procesoru]+" "+[0_PRODUKTY]![Procesor]
```

*<sub>Počet jader CPU = number of CPU cores

Značka procesoru = CPU manufacturer</sub>*

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, always use the ampersand `&` operator when concatenating data in VBA: the `&` operator will always interpret data as a string (where possible), whereas the addition `+` operator will sum numerical data, even if such data is presented as a string.

---

Since you are compiling a description from your various fields, I would suggest using a text box with the control source:

```vb
=[0_PRODUKTY]![Počet jader CPU] & "-core processor " & [0_PRODUKTY]![Značka procesoru] & " " & [0_PRODUKTY]![Procesor]
```

You could also force the string conversion of numerical fields using the `CStr` function, which coerces a variant argument to a string:

```vb
=CStr([Počet jader CPU]) & "-core processor " & [0_PRODUKTY]![Značka procesoru] & " " & [0_PRODUKTY]![Procesor]
```

Note that you may also need to account for null fields.

Comment: So, it almost works now, thank you for your help sir. I mean, the values are correct, but they're just numbers instead of strings - as shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/f5BVm05)

Comment: @uselessguy28 You're most welcome; I have updated my answer above with an additional suggestion which should hopefully solve this issue.

Comment: `=[Počet jader CPU] & "jádrový procesor " & CStr([Značka procesoru]) & " " & CStr([Procesor])` produces the exact same results, numbers instead of strings :/

Comment: Tried that as well, but it keeps asking for a parameter called `0_PRODUKTY`. And it seemed odd to convert something that's supposed to be a number instead of things which aren't. Just to clarify, the lookup tables all contain the neccessary strings - https://imgur.com/a/FdiLxHz

Comment: As I understood from your screenshots, `[Počet jader CPU]` is numerical and should therefore be converted to a string.

Comment: Ooooooh, now i get it. Like, a type conflict. You got it right, but for some reason, it doesn't work. Maybe you could have a look in the .accdb file?